# IBAction sometimes not being called when touching buttons - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, touch, ibaction

I am trying to develop a word game where players click buttons to select letters.

There seems to be problem where my buttons sometimes do not register touches.  It only seems to occur if there is a pause for a few seconds with no user interaction before a button touch. If the first touch works, quick follow up touches also work.

```
@IBAction func tileButton1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Tile 1 Selected")
    tileSelected(tileSelected: 1)
}

@IBAction func clearButton(_ sender: Any) {
    clearSelectedTiles()
}


@IBAction func SubmitButton(_ sender: Any) {
    //print("Submit Button Pressed")
    checkIfSubmittedWordIsValid()
}
```

checkIfSubmittedWordIsValid

```
func checkIfSubmittedWordIsValid() {
    var alreadySelectedWords: [String] = []
    switch currentPlayer {
    case 1:
        alreadySelectedWords = player1words
    case 2:
        alreadySelectedWords = player2words
    case 3:
        alreadySelectedWords = player3words
    case 4:
        alreadySelectedWords = player4words
    default:
        break
    }
    if currentWord.characters.count < 3 {
        print("Too short")
        playSound(fileName: "invalidWord", fileExtension: "aiff", volume: 1.0)
    } else if alreadySelectedWords.contains(currentWord) {
        print("Already picked this word")
        playSound(fileName: "invalidWord", fileExtension: "aiff", volume: 1.0)
    } else if wordList.contains(currentWord.lowercased()) {
        print("Valid Word")
        playSound(fileName: "goodWord", fileExtension: "wav", volume: 0.5)
        addWordToPlayerList(word: currentWord)
    } else {
        print("Not in dictionary")
        playSound(fileName: "invalidWord", fileExtension: "aiff", volume: 1.0)
    }
    clearSelectedTiles()
}
```

clearSelectedTiles

```
func clearSelectedTiles() {
    tile1.alpha = 1
    tile2.alpha = 1
    tile3.alpha = 1
    tile4.alpha = 1
    tile5.alpha = 1
    tile6.alpha = 1
    tile7.alpha = 1
    tile8.alpha = 1
    tile9.alpha = 1
    tile10.alpha = 1
    tile11.alpha = 1
    tile12.alpha = 1
    tile13.alpha = 1
    tile14.alpha = 1
    tile15.alpha = 1
    tile16.alpha = 1
    selectedTiles.removeAll()
    validTiles = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
    selectedWordLabel.text = ""
    currentWord = ""
}
```

Nothing gets printed when the issue occurs.  Following up quickly with a second touch will trigger the IBAction and print to log.

It seems to happen also with all my other buttons (another 15 'tile' buttons and a 'Clear' and 'Submit' button)

What am I doing wrong?

[Link to video showing issue](https://youtu.be/KPznBr7ZSC0)  First few touches work but then weirdness.

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Touch Down event]

tileSelected

```
func tileSelected(tileSelected: Int) {
    if isTileValid(tile: tileSelected) {
        selectedTiles.append(tileSelected)
        var surroundingTiles: [Int] = []
        switch tileSelected {
        case 1:
            tile1.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [2,5,6]
        case 2:
            tile2.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [1,3,5,6,7]
        case 3:
            tile3.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [2,4,6,7,8]
        case 4:
            tile4.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [3,7,8]
        case 5:
            tile5.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [1,2,6,9,10]
        case 6:
            tile6.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [1,2,3,5,7,9,10,11]
        case 7:
            tile7.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [2,3,4,6,8,10,11,12]
        case 8:
            tile8.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [3,4,7,11,12]
        case 9:
            tile9.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [5,6,10,13,14]
        case 10:
            tile10.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [5,6,7,9,11,13,14,15]
        case 11:
            tile11.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [6,7,8,10,12,14,15,16]
        case 12:
            tile12.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [7,8,11,15,16]
        case 13:
            tile13.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [9,10,14]
        case 14:
            tile14.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [9,10,11,13,15]
        case 15:
            tile15.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [10,11,12,14,16]
        case 16:
            tile16.alpha = 0.5
            surroundingTiles = [11,12,15]
        default:
            // do nothing
            break
        }
        updateValidTiles(surroundingTiles: surroundingTiles)
        //print("Updated Valid Tiles")
        //print(validTiles)
        //print("Selected Tiles")
        //print(selectedTiles)
        currentWord = currentWord + boardTiles[tileSelected - 1].tileLetter
        selectedWordLabel.text = currentWord
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set action for event touch Up Inside.

Comment: did you try with touch up inside event?

Comment: the problems in your video only start when you click your "Submit" button.  What is happening in your Submit function?  How do you clear the button highlighted states?  Show your code for that.

Comment: please show your function to handle your submit action

Comment: @Nirav D I've tried it with Touch up inside and no difference.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann Added more code as requested.  However it is doing the same thing after clicking 'Clear' button.  Possibly also after just clicking other tiles.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann Confirmed, also occurs without having pressed 'clear' or 'submit'

Comment: Your stackViews may be messing stuff up. Not sure but maybe something to look into.

Comment: Weird. I have been removing bits of code trying to find the cause.  Removing the `override var prefersStatusBarHidden` seems to eliminate the issue. But why?  I want to keep the status bar hidden.

Comment: what is code for tileSelected(tileSelected: 1) ?

Comment: @Sunil Added func

Comment: please add breakpoint in IBAction of any 16 button and check second also calling this methods or not

Comment: @Ro4ch  I tried removing the stack views and there was no change. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: are u check second time this method calling? when again clicking on button. please confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some labels constrained to the `Top Layout Guide.bottom` even though I was hiding the status bar with `override var prefersStatusBarHidden`.

Changing the relevant label constraints to `topMargin` instead of `Top Layout Guide.bottom` has solved my problem with touches sometimes being missed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing touch down to touch up inside, and try changing the state of the button each time it is clicked